# Use array find() method instead of for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

How can we use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method instead of for loop in this code ?

```
onLoadTickets() {
    const ticketsReq = this.ticketService.getTickets();
    const tariffsReq = this.tariffService.getTariffs();

    forkJoin([ticketsReq, tariffsReq]).subscribe(results => {
      const data = results[0];
      const tariffResp = results[1];
      this.tickets = data.requests;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.tickets.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < tariffResp.tariffs?.length; j++) {
          if (tariffResp.tariffs[j].id == this.tickets[i].tariffId) {
            this.tickets[i].tariff = tariffResp.tariffs[j]
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

**Note :**

Using `find()` method is not mandatory. I have to write this code with any array methods.

**Edit :**
I have used map() and includes() methods. my solution:

```
const tariffIds = tariffResp.tariffs.map((tariff: Tariffs) => tariff.id);
      this.tickets.map((item) => {
        if (tariffResp.tariffs === null || tariffResp.tariffs === undefined) {
          return item;
        }
        if (tariffIds.includes(item.tariffId)) {
          item.tariff = tariffResp.tariffs[tariffIds.indexOf(item.tariffId)];
        }
        return item;
      });
```

This works but I'm not sure it's the best solution

Comment: You need map here, because you are assinging value based on condition and array values being changed after that.

Comment: @GRD yes, I used map() and it is working. thanks!

Comment: If that is the solution, then please add it in the answer space below, not as an update to the question

Answer (score 1):

[Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

So, if in your case you only have one tariff against all the tickets then you can go ahead with `Array.find()` but if you have multiple tariff and multiple tickets then you can go ahead with `Array.filter()`.

Demo with `Array.find()` **:**

```js
const tickets = [{
    tariffId: 1,
  name: 'Ticket 1'
}, {
    tariffId: 2,
  name: 'Ticket 2'
}];

const tariffResp = {
    tariffs: [{
    id: 1
  }]
};

const result = tickets.find((obj) => tariffResp.tariffs[0].id);

console.log(result);
```

Demo with `Array.map()` along with `Array.filter()` **:**

```js
const tickets = [{
    tariffId: 1,
  name: 'Ticket 1'
}, {
    tariffId: 2,
  name: 'Ticket 2'
}, {
    tariffId: 3,
  name: 'Ticket 3'
}];

const tariffResp = {
    tariffs: [{
    id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2
  }]
};

const result = tariffResp.tariffs.map((obj) => {
    return tickets.filter((ticketObj) => obj.id === ticketObj.tariffId);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I tried to solve it with map(). it works but I'm not sure it's the best solution. I edited the question. thank you

Comment: This is best solution to handle the things with two different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.tickets=data.request.map(x=>{
  const obj:any=x;
  obj.tariff=tariffResp.find(t=>t.id==x.tariffId)
  return obj
})
```

You loop over data.request using map. map transform an array in another

First you create an object with the values of x

After you add a new propety "tariff" that is the "tariffResp" who has the "id" property equal to the property "tariffId" of x

Check [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods of an array

Comment: I have used map() and inclused(). Please check my edit. thank you